# How can I send an "Access Denied" http response to the client in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In my page load I check something, and I want to display the standard Access Denied message without going through the hassle of creating a page to redirect to.

Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Response.Clear()    
Response.Write("Access Denied")
Response.StatusCode = 401;
Response.End()
```

Comment: It would not work if there were some other stuff already written to the output. At least, do a Response.Clear() beforehand.
If you want the standard http way of saying access denied, using StatusCode is the way to go, though.

Comment: A better solution would be to send back the status code for Unauthorized, 401. See the answer from Yann Schwartz.

Comment: @user707727 Indeed. Edited the answer to reflect Yann's answer.

Answer (score 30):

You want to return a HTTP return code of 401 ("access denied")

So,

```
Response.Clear();
Response.StatusCode = 401;
Response.End();
```

should do the trick

Comment: This is definitely the better answer. Other applications requesting your page will look at the status code and be able to determine what happened.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do something like

```
throw new HttpException(401, "Access Denied");
```

Answer (score 1):

To send this before any other output, you have a couple of options.

One, create a HTTPHandler module, add this to web.config. This sees ASP.NET pipeline events before the page gets control, so if you can determine at that point that you don't want the page to run, you can send the 401 before the page does anything. The handler inherits IHTTPHandler, so start searching on that interface definition for documentation.

Second, you can hook into the page events PreInit and Init, and send the 401 before the Page Load method starts. Since the page class is created by this time, you can also set a flag in the page object that other methods can check to see if the page is responding with 401.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
try{
    //try smth
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx){
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, UAEx.Message);
}
return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

With .net Core you will achieve it with returning `UnauthorizedResult` or `UnauthorizedObjectResult`.